# Best way to handle if-else with argparse?

Tags: python, if-statement, argparse

Say we have a lot of options for argument parsing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download files from Canvas.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-user_id',
        type=str,
        default="",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-course_id',
        type=str,
        default="",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-student_id',
        type=str,
        default="",
    )
# ...
    parser.add_argument(
        '-book_id',
        type=str,
        default="",
    )
```

And I want to run functions determined by the inputs

```
if user_id != "" and course_id == "" and student_id != "" and book_id == "":
    f()

elif user_id != "" and course_id == "" and student_id != "" and book_id != "":
    g()

# ...

elif user_id == "" and course_id == "" and student_id == "" and book_id == "":
    h()
```

and so on. Well, these are a lot of if-else statements. I want to eliminate having to do all of that. Does anyone have sufficient ways to reduce the amount of comparisons among variables before a function is run? Or does it depend on context? Thank you!!

Comment: If you omit the `default` parameters, the default default would be `None`.  So `user_id==""` can be written as `user_id is None` (or `is not None)`)  That may/or may not be clear.

Comment: Thank you. Will also implement that into my code. @hpaulj Must have missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a dictionary that maps a combination of options to a handler function.

When you write this:

```
if user_id != "" and course_id == "" and student_id != "" and book_id == "":
```

You are effectively treating those four options as a tuple of boolean
values. You are asking, "are the arguments equal to (False, True,
False, True)?"

We can take advantage of that.  First, we need code to translate the
options into an actual tuple. Something like:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
sig = tuple(getattr(args, x) == '' for x in ('user_id', 'course_id', 'student_id', 'book_id'))
```

If your program receives no command line arguments, this sets `sig`
equal to `(True, True, True, True)`. If you pass `--student-id 1`,
this becomes `(True, True, False, True)`.

We can create a dictionary that maps these patterns to a handler
function:

```
argmap = {
    (False, True, False, True): f,
    (False, True, False, False): g,
    (True, True, True, True): h,
}
```

With these two mechanisms in hand, we can look up the handler for a
given set of arguments like this:

```
handler = argmap.get(sig)
if handler is None:
    print('no handler for', args)
else:
    handler()
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
import argparse


def f():
    print('this is function f')


def g():
    print('this is function g')


def h():
    print('this is function h')


argmap = {
    (False, True, False, True): f,
    (False, True, False, False): g,
    (True, True, True, True): h,
}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download files from Canvas.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--user-id',
        default='',
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--course-id',
        default='',
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--student-id',
        default='',
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--book-id',
        default='',
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    sig = tuple(getattr(args, x) == '' for x in ('user_id', 'course_id', 'student_id', 'book_id'))
    handler = argmap.get(sig)
    if handler is None:
        print('no handler for', args)
    else:
        handler()
```

This produces as output:

```
$ python argtest.py
this is function h
$ python argtest.py --user-id 1 --student-id 1
this is function f
$ python argtest.py --user-id 1 --student-id 1 --book-id 1
this is function g
$ python argtest.py --user-id 1
no handler for Namespace(user_id='1', course_id='', student_id='', book_id='')
```

Comment: Great method! Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I was just wondering, but what if the functions have arguments? It seems that the function runs before being parsed in the tuple. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the function runs before being parsed in the tuple". The function only runs when you call it, in that final `handler()` line. If you want to pass arguments, just put them in the function call like any other function. You'll want to make sure that all your handler functions accept the same set of arguments.

Comment: Thanks! After some research, I found out what I was doing wrong.